# what code should i write after the object definition to print all the fun method

Tags: python, printing

```
class ApnaCollege():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print(self.x)
    def fun(self):
        print("I am a function with no argument")
    
    def fun(self,x):
        print("The function with an argument")

    def fun(self,x,y):
        print("The function with an two argument")

obj = ApnaCollege()

obj.fun()
obj.fun(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

To see all the methods of an object defined by a class:

```
dir(obj)
```

You can find more info here: [Ask Python: How to find all the methods of a given class in Python?](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/find-all-methods-of-class#:%7E:text=To%20list%20the%20methods%20for%20this%20class%2C%20one%20approach%20is,and%20properties%20of%20the%20class.) including how to filter out dunder methods and get the methods you explicitly defined.